# How to implement closed user management in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-identity

I am trying to built a web based small school management system with asp.net. I am new to mvc, and so searching and learning about it for a while. Recently I found the microsoft's step by step training guide to create a complete "Contoso University" project which is very much helpfull in my case. But the problem is the project does not included Authentication and Authorization. I later found that this could be implemented using **asp.net Identity**, but in my case the system should have somewhat a closed usership. That means **random users who have a valid email or google or facebook account, should NOT be able to "Register" with the system** and then get access to it. Instead there should be **a default Admin user, who inturn, will add/edit new user accounts to the system**, define their access lavel and then the userid-password will be provided to the intended users for login.

I have searched a lot about this. I have found different article about **role based security**. But frankly none of them is completely applicable for my case.
So here I am again. Any help in this regard will be appriciated.

Comment: My understanding is that asp.identity allows anyone to register but you should be able to ensure that an admin still approves that - sorry I don't have specifics though. Is this an Internet facing application or Intranet-only application. I you know for sure that it will only ever be Intranet, use windows authentication. If it's internet facing then keep in mind that a site that makes me think of a new login/password is annoying. A site that lets me reuse my windows or google email is convenient.

Comment: Also consider: if your school has already implemented Office 365 - i.e. they are already logging on to Outlook 365 web with a given account, then you should really reuse that (Organizational Accounts) rather than forcing creation of a new login/password

Comment: No the school do not have Office 365, and the application will be Intranet based for now, but could be implemented to internet later. Anyway, even in that case I still want to use Indivisual User Accounts because I need to assign specific access level for specific user which is more easy to implement for idivisual account... or so I belive.

Comment: You can remove all the external login systems and all the logic for creating and managing accounts - usually the AccountController and ManageController. I have a similar set up but for me the accounts are created nightly based on security groups and injected into the database. The admin's then set the role the following day. This can also be done via an Admin view where admin's provide the username and password for an account. In this case reuse the logic in the Admin controller's register method.

Comment: If your school is on windows then perhaps you should windows authentication. Then you just "flip a switch" to designate whether a given windows user has access to your web app. I must stress again: No one wants to have to remember another login/password. The whole issuing logins and passwords thing is really out of date.

Comment: OK so how about letting the users register with their email/facebook account, while giving a "GUEST" role to the new user. Then the admin could assign different role to the exsisting acount for further access. Will this work?

Comment: That's what I meant in my first comment. I don't see that they even need a  guest. They could have a 'pending' which means they can't even get in until someone approves

Comment: I see. Ok then, how can I implement admin approval? Is their any proper guide?